# Condensing Perl Transpose code

Tags: perl

I always find myself writing code like this:

```
my $var = $result[0];
my $var_changed = $var;
$var_changed =~ s/somepattern/somechange/g;
```

What would be a better way to do this? And by 'better' I mean: less typing while remaining understandable.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This would do the same thing as the second and third lines;

```
(my $var_changed = $var) =~ s/somepattern/somechange/g;
```

How legible it is is your call.

Comment: Legibility aside, it's very idiomatic and something you're likely to see in code written by experienced Perl developers.

Answer (score 1):

Or even

```
(my $var_changed = my $var = $result[0]) =~ s/somepattern/somechange/g;
```

But that starts to bring into question why you need $var in the first place.